# What prevents (illegitimate) operation of NFC with higher power?

Tags: nfc

I was going to post this on Information Security, but Elecrical Engineering may possibly be a better fit since it's more about the technical side.

Like most people nowadays, I am left with no choice but to have a NFC chip on my credit and debit cards. Although you can tell the bank not to enable NFC payments (which I did), the chip will nevertheless tell anyone asking the credit card number and validity date, in plaintext. That's just how it works.

Now, the NFC propaganda states that this is perfectly safe because it only works up to 4 centimeters range (although other sources say 30cm), so someone would have to get extremely close to you, which is none more risk than any other card because they could as well steal the card.

Disregarding EM regulations, which a criminal couldn't care about less... what exactly prevents a criminal standing a meter or two behind me from using, well, a slightly bigger antenna, maybe a directional one with a reflector hidden under the T-Shirt, and a *somewhat* stronger sender, so the signal is for example a thousand times (let's say 1024 times) stronger than what's used in the card reader terminal. The square root of 1024 is 32, so that should provide the field intensity necessary to power up the chip (and make it reply) at 32 times the distance, respectively 32*4 = 128 centimeters. Or, assume 4096 times stronger for 2.5 meters range.

A credit card terminal (the entire thing including display and all) has a total power consumption of about 2W. So it's not unreasonable to assume that the sender is rather... weakish. The antenna can't be much larger than 3-4 centimeters either. Even more so as e.g. in Europe no more than 10mW ERP is generally allowed at all for frequencies below 27MHz. So it's probably something "single-digit milli", or "micro".

Surely it is possible, and easy, to carry a sender that is a thousand times stronger than that?

Of course, using a high-power sender might accidentially "fry" someone's chip when getting too close, but again, what does a criminal care about frying *my* card.

Comment: Or the NFC doesn't contain all that info but just a NFC chip ID that is communicated to the issuer to get the proper account info linked to it.

Comment: It's not really an antenna, it's a coil. The coil needs to scale up too, a rule of thumb is ReadRange ~= Coil Diameter. Beyond that the field decays by distance cubed. And when the coil gets over 1/4 wavelength circumference, 6 m, things start to go wobbly. Still I imagine a >1 m range is fairly easy to do.

Comment: Perfectly possible to communicate with further away, maybe not several meters, but certainly from a rucksack to some passerby. Which is btw. exactly what some people at defcon love to do.

Comment: Here's your opportunity to market aluminum-coated wallets, pockets, underwear for the wary public. Third-party monitoring might be a more difficult problem to overcome than direct excitation.

Comment: @glen_geek, aluminum won't work.  NFC works by mutual inductance between the coil in the reader and the coil in the card.  You'll need a [Mu-Metal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mu-metal) wallet.

Comment: Greater distance definitely doable. MUCH greater is hard. | IF the NFC is not ever essential to operation then NFC loop can (probably) be broken by placing card on light table, locating NFC coil track safely away from other 'stuff' and drilling a very small hole to break track. |I keep meaning to do this on my card. Never manage to get to it yet. Some banks will disable the service. Mine won't.

Comment: @Russell - you and me both (after a rash of "range" questions here) ... some earlier cards allowed enough light through that you could see the antenna for drilling; a newer one was opaque. But after complaining (and some card surgery) my bank sent me - out of the blue, after claiming it was impossible - the plain old Chip&Pin I use now.

Comment: Aluminum works, above 4MHz or so. Only get a few dB attenuation for 3mil foil at 4MHz. At 40MHz, you'll get sqrt(40/4) = sqrt(10) = 3.16 nepers attenuation; with 8.6 dB per neper, you'll have 30dB attenuation at 40MHz. With default thickness AL foil.